# VB6 to vb.net conversion BaseControlArray

Tags: vb.net

The designer must create an instance of type 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.BaseControlArray' but it cannot because the type is declared as abstract.

Answer (score 1):

In VB6 it was possible to create an array of controls in the Designer, just by adding an index property. That's not possible in vb.net. Instead, in order to have an array of controls, you have to declare the array of controls in the program and add them to the form's controls collection.